# How to restore BCDEdit to default?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bcdedit

I had the ubuntu\winboot\wubildr.mbr file missing, which kept coming up in the boot sequence. So I ran terminal as administrator and typed in bcdedit /delete identifier (which was under  Real-mode boot sector)
But all it was remove the message and sent me straight into Windows, which is the worst thing to have happened.

How do I put the settings back to before the deletion?

Thanks so much, it seems like everything is going wrong now.

Answer (score 2):

bcdedit /create /d “Linux” /application bootsector
BCDEdit will return an alphanumeric identifier for this entry that I will refer to as {ID} in the remaining steps. You’ll need to replace {ID} by the actual returned identifier. An example of {ID} is {d7294d4e-9837-11de-99ac-f3f3a79e3e93}. Next, let’s specify which partition hosts a copy of the linux.bin file:

bcdedit /set {ID} device partition=c:
The path to our linux.bin file:

bcdedit /set {ID}  path \linux.bin
An entry to the displayed menu at boot time:

bcdedit /displayorder {ID} /addlast
and finally, let’s specify how long the menu choices will be displayed:

bcdedit /timeout 30
That’s it! Now reboot and you will be presented with menu where you can choose to boot to Windows 7 or Linux. When you choose Linux, you’ll be taken to the GRUB menu where you can choose to continue booting your Linux distribution.

On a final note, if at any time you want to eliminate the Linux menu option simply delete the BCD store entry you created using the following command:

bcdedit /delete {ID}